# How can I continue a WebRTC stream on Android&iOS when I change the mobile network from wifi to 4G

Tags: android, ios, webrtc

I develop an Android App based WebRTC, I have a problem now, as I in a stream conference with my App, I changed my mobile network, from wifi to 4G or 4G to wifi, the stream is not working, do I have to recreate a new PeerConnection? Thanks for attention.

Comment: There is no need to create new peerConnection However you have to re-initiate(reconnect) your connection to the server. Because when you change the network connection lost or break.

Comment: @Daljeet could you please explain more the re-initiate(reconnect) part? Details on ice Candidates, SDPs created or any Media constraints if needed.